# Create a guaranteed exception safe method in C#

Tags: c#, exception

I recently implemented a function which logs object contents using JSON.SerializeObject.

To cut a long story short, the idea was, that this function would be used in our newly implemented logging mechanism, to track objects when needed, based on system parameterization.

One absolute requirement for the entire logging mechanism, was that it should never throw exceptions, because it would be used extensively. Any developer should be able to use it and under no circumstances should this function cause any interruption in code flow. In case of failure, any call should simply be skipped.

After implementing it and having inspected and handled every exception that I could think of, I decided to wrap the entire functionality in an outer try-catch block, just in case.

Like so:

```
public static void TrackObject(object obj)
{
   try { Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj)); }
   catch { Console.WriteLine("Failed to track object."); }
}
```

After passing all tests with flying colors, I fired up the main application to do some actual environment testing.
To my surprise, due to a Nuget misconfiguration, my function caused an exception (System.IO.FileLoadException) after it was called, but before it entered the try-catch block and so it propagated back to the main application, causing havoc to code flow.

This got me thinking.

There are ways for exceptions to be thrown while calling the function but before a handler kicks in. There are also cases where an exception is simply unacceptable.

My current solution, was to create a wrapper function, which simply calls the actual function inside a try-catch. But this looks ugly and wrong. Plus I am not sure it is a bullet proof solution.

```
public static void TrackObject(object obj)
{
   try { PrivateTrackObject(obj); }
   catch { Console.WriteLine("Failed to track object."); }
}

private static void PrivateTrackObject(object obj)
{
   Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj));
}
```

**Is there a way to create a bullet-proof, no-way in hell, exception free method?**

Or at least **is there a definitive list of exceptions that can occur on a method call?**

PS. The compiler warned me about the version mismatch, but I didn’t see it the first time.

PS2. I have created a sample project for anyone who wishes to see this issue in action.
https://drive.google.com/open?id=15BDrLNn87gsMHc9pQ-TgyDMSLQxDBq18

Comment: If there was a way to create an "exception-free" method, then exceptions would cease to exist.  I have to admit, I still don't really understand what you are asking but it seems like your question is too broad

Comment: Writing never-fail code is pretty unwise.  Major migraine when it does fail and you have zero leads to find out why.  Luckily the jitter blew a raspberry at this feeble attempt so it could still tell you what went wrong.  And it only took you a couple of minutes.  Feature, not a bug.

Comment: @maccettura While, for reasons mentioned in my answer, you can't eliminate *all* exceptions from your programs, you can certainly structure your own code to use different error handling mechanisms than exceptions.  You could, for example, use error code to indicate errors rather than exceptions (possibly even catching all exceptions from any framework code you call and turning it into a returned error code).  While some people (myself included) like the model of using exceptions for error handling, that doesn't mean it's the only way to design an application.

Comment: @Servy I interpreted OP's question like the first part of your answer (i.e no way to create an exception free method), but I also agree with your comment (there are other ways to indicate errors).

Comment: @Hans Passant I couldn't agree more with your point. But there are some times where a piece of code does something non-essential (aka you can keep going without it). My particular implementation does exactly that. My problem is that an exception occurred inside my function, but not in place I can handle it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a way to create a bullet-proof, no-way in hell, exception free method?

No.  Even if the method is literally empty you can always have a thread abort exception thrown, or a stack overflow exception if there isn't enough space on the stack to call that method, or it could result in an out of memory exception.

> is there a definitive list of exceptions that can occur on a method call?

If it's arbitrary code (i.e. from a delegate) then no.  It could always be a custom exception of some type that didn't even exist when you wrote your code.

---

Also note that in your situation you need to be concerned about any possible exceptions that could be thrown *in your catch block*, if you just want to try handling normal exceptions (unlike the ones mentioned above) that happen in your `try` block.  Just logging the exception could fail.  In your example of using the console there could be problems with standard output that result in an exception.  If you're really going for *this code never throws* you'd need to try to log the exceptions, but have other backup logging options for when they aren't working (and if you really can't throw, which as mentioned by others, is almost certainly a bad idea, then you need to be willing to go on without logging if logging your exceptions is failing).

Comment: Thanks for replying. The actual code is quite extensive. It uses NLog, falls back to custom mechanism which also falls back to Trace.WriteLine (just to report the exception).
The “no exception” is a deliberate decision. If you can’t log, inform about it (when and why) so it can be fixed, but don’t mess up program execution.
My question has to do with how can I make sure that unexpected issues with no detrimental effect (such as a reference version mismatch) does not mess the entire application? Examples like the ones you mention (StackOverflowException) would affect the application anyway.

Comment: @Phasmagon By definition, you cannot expect and prevent all unexpected issues.  You can expect and prevent certain specific issues that you've thought of.

Comment: True. But can you imagine the position my employer (and by extension I) will be put in, if this kind of bug was missed by me or out QA department and found it's way on the customer's environment?
As a side note this type of logging is mostly used for a part of the application that integrates with external services, for which we code "blindly" (using API references and Dev guides without actually connecting to them), so our QA cannot catch most issues there.
This particular issue is easy to identify and resolve. What worries me is what other exception can be thrown that I have not thought of.